# How to create a hover effect within input and label elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here my aim is to replace the images wrapped up in labels with the list of images using the hover effect. I currently use the Jquery `click` functionality to show and hide the list of images however I would also like to introduce the hover effect using the same images in the same position.

HTML:

```
<div id="formone">
<input type="radio" name="starrate" value="1.0" id="b"/>
<label for="b"><img id="img1"  src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

<input type="radio" name="starrate" value="2.0" id="c">
<label for="c" ><img id="img3"  src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

<input type="radio" name="starrate" value="3.0" id="d"/>
<label for="d" ><img id="img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>
</div>

<ul>
<li>
<img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
<img id="img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
<img id="img6" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}

#img1, #img3, #img5 {
width: 100px;
height:100px;
}

#img2{
bottom: 25px;
}
#img4 {
bottom: 50px;
}
#img6 {
bottom: 75px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$("img[id='img2']").css({"display": "none"});
$("img[id='img4']").css({"display": "none"});
$("img[id='img6']").css({"display": "none"});

    $("#img1").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img2']").show();
        $("img[id='img4']").hide();
       $("img[id='img6']").hide();
    });

    $("img[id='img3']").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img4']").show();
        $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        $("img[id='img6']").hide();
    });

     $("img[id='img5']").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img6']").show();
        $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        $("img[id='img4']").hide();
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqb0oyy4/

Comment: just hover to show images or you want also check radio button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`data attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```js
$('ul img').hide();

$('label img').hover(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).show();
  $(target).siblings().hide();
})
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#img1, #img3, #img5 {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}

#img2{
  bottom: 25px;
}
#img4 {
  bottom: 50px;
}
#img6 {
  bottom: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formone">
  <input type="radio" name="starrate" value="1.0" id="b"/>
  <label for="b"><img data-target="#img2" id="img1"  src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

  <input type="radio" name="starrate" value="2.0" id="c">
  <label for="c" ><img id="img3" data-target="#img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

  <input type="radio" name="starrate" value="3.0" id="d"/>
  <label for="d" ><img id="img5" data-target="#img6" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>
    <img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
    <img id="img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
    <img id="img6" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very good answer! Is there a way of going back to its original state once the mouse leaves the image? I suppose I should post another question

Comment: You mean you want to hide all images in list again once mouse leave?

Comment: But once clicked it stays...The clallback does not make the image stay where it is once clicked

Comment: I've posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102891/how-to-create-mouseover-and-mouseleave-effect-within-input-and-label-elements)